# Original Lotka–Volterra model

Tags: ecology, theoretical-biology, literature, population-dynamics

I am looking for the articles in which Lotka and Volterra published their original predator prey model. I couldn’t find the model presented in many textbooks in Lotka’s book *Elements of Physical Biology* or Volterra’s paper *Fluctuations in the Abundance of a Species considered Mathematically.*

Is there really Lotka–Volterra model for dynamics of two  competing species? On Wikipedia and Murray’s book *Mathematical Biology: an Introduction,* it is written that it exists but I couldn’t find it in their papers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volterra’s [*Variations and Fluctuations of the Number of Individuals in Animal Species living together*](https://doi.org/10.1093/icesjms/3.1.3) features what is nowadays often called the generalised Lotka–Volterra model.
Thus it captures competition between and with populations.
In particular, Section 2 is titled:

> Biological Association of two Species which contend for the same Food.